# Foreign key not able to get one to many working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework

I want to have a one to many relation with player points but I need it in such a way that entity framework sees it as a collection so i can add to it. I mean that one player can have multiple points requests.

Player Table [image]

Player Points Table[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[player](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_player_id]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [Name] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [player_id] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [address] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [gender] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [town] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [zipcode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [telephone] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [email] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [active] [bit] NULL,
    [createdDate] [date] NULL,
    [author] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [siteid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [regEmailSent] [bit] NULL,
    [regEmailActivated] [bit] NULL,
    [teamId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [isDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [deletedDate] [date] NULL,
    [modifiedDate] [date] NULL,
    [modifiedBy] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [isArchived] [bit] NULL,
    [districtId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [dob] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_player] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[player]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_player_team] FOREIGN KEY([teamId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[team] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[player] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_player_team]
GO
```

How do i add a foreign so that A player can have many point rows the field that im using to link them with is playerId.
And My Player Points Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[player_points](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_player_points_id]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [playerId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [playerName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [teamId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [points] [int] NULL,
    [pointsToRedeem] [int] NULL,
    [dateToBeAwarded] [date] NULL,
    [approvedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [approved] [bit] NULL,
    [approvedDate] [date] NULL,
    [siteId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [sentApproveEmail] [bit] NULL,
    [isActivated] [bit] NULL,
    [authUserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [authCreatedDate] [date] NULL,
    [modifiedDate] [date] NULL,
    [modifiedBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [playerNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [isProcessed] [bit] NULL,
    [sentEmailToAdmin] [bit] NULL,
    [sentEmailToUser] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_player_points] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stuck this is how I had to add my foreign key on the actual points table and not the player table I no school boy error but thanks to all for helping.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[player_points](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_player_points_id]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [playerId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [playerName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [teamId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [points] [int] NULL,
    [pointsToRedeem] [int] NULL,
    [dateToBeAwarded] [date] NULL,
    [approvedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [approved] [bit] NULL,
    [approvedDate] [date] NULL,
    [siteId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [sentApproveEmail] [bit] NULL,
    [isActivated] [bit] NULL,
    [authUserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [authCreatedDate] [date] NULL,
    [modifiedDate] [date] NULL,
    [modifiedBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [playerNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [isProcessed] [bit] NULL,
    [sentEmailToAdmin] [bit] NULL,
    [sentEmailToUser] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_player_points] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[player_points]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PlayerPoints] FOREIGN KEY([playerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[player] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[player_points] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PlayerPoints]
GO
```